# Custom dataset performance issue

Tags: c#, dataset

In runtime my app gets data from MSSQL server and there's an object that pulls the data into my custom dataset. 
Here's the code:

```
public static void FillRegionData(int country, RegionDataTable DestinationTable)
{
  DestinationTable.Clear();
  using (selectRegionsListTableAdapter _taSource = new selectRegionsListTableAdapter())
  {
    BusStationDataSet.selectRegionsListDataTable _tblSource = _taSource.GetData(country, Settings.Default.DataLanguage);
    foreach (BusStationDataSet.selectRegionsListRow row in _tblSource.Rows)
    {
      DestinationTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 
        row.region,
        row.country,
        row.title });
    }

  }
}
```

Everything goes fine until foreach starts working. A bit more than 100 rows causes the whole app to hang for several seconds.

Any ideas why this code is so slow?

Comment: Are you sure about this method being culprit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about this. I tried inserting "throw new Exception();" after the "foreach" stuff and it got ages for exception to be thrown.

Comment: implementation of DestinationTable?

Comment: public class RegionDataTable : DataTable {  RegionDataTable() { this.TableName = "Region"; this.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("regionId", typeof(int))); this.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("country", typeof(int))); this.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("title", typeof(string)));  } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `DestinationTable` perhaps data-bound at this point? Since `DataTable` issues change notifications, adding lots of data while bound will cause a performance bottleneck. In many cases you can simply suspend the data-binding while you do this. Or alternatively, populate it **first**, and *then* give it to the data-binding.

(the difference here is whether it redraws and refreshes the UI once per *row*, or once *overall*)

Comment: DestinationTable is the data source for databinding. I have combobox items bound to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After some googling I firgured that it would be more efficient if I'd used diffirenet dataset for each datasource.